# understanding $' ' quotes in bash

Tags: bash, syntax, quotes

At least in bash pattern substitution following quotes are often used: `$' '` For example `${arr[@]/%/$'\n\n\n'}` prints three newline characters after each array "arr" item. Are those some sort of special quotes? How are they called? Where are they used besides bash pattern substitution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[ANSI-C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)

> Words of the form `$'string'` are treated specially. The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.

---

For example:

```
$'hello\nworld'
```

You'll get `11` characters with **newline** in the middle.

---

```
echo -e 'hello\nworld'
echo   $'hello\nworld'
```

They give you the same result.